# How do I find words with three or more vowels (of the same kind) with regex using back referencing?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

How can I find words with three **or more** vowels **of the same kind** with a regular expression using back referencing?

I'm searching in text with a 3-column tab format "Word+PoS+Lemma".

This is what I have so far:

```bash
ggrep -P -i --colour=always '^\w*([aeioueöäüèéà])\w*?\1\w*?\1\w*?\t' filename
```

However, this gives me words with three vowels but not of the same kind.
I'm confused, because I thought the back referencing would refer to the same vowel it found in the brackets? I solved this problem by changing the `.*?` to `\w*`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: do you consider `è` and `e` to be "of the same kind"?

Comment: Do you mean in the results? Then no.

Comment: Your pattern [looks good](https://regex101.com/r/EQCIVE/1). Maybe there is some other issue.

Comment: Hmm, but how do I achieve the "and more" part? Right now it just matches it three times... @bobblebubble

Comment: Add multiple matching and non matching examples to your question.

Comment: @sgelena [This matches 3 **or more**](https://regex101.com/r/Q4sKLZ/1), just the requirement is three. To require min e.g. 5 you're better off using a quantified group: [`^\w*?([aeioueöäüèéà])(?:\w*?\1){5}\w*\t`](https://regex101.com/r/Z5G2U4/1)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex looks too complicated, not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `.*?` but the usage looks suspect.  I'd use something like:

```
([aeioueöäüèéà])\1\1
```

i.e. match a vowel as a capture group, then say you need two more.

Didn't realise you wanted to allow other letters between vowels, just allow zero or more "word" letters between backreferences:

```
([aeioueöäüèéà])(\w*\1){2}
```

Comment: demo: https://regexr.com/6vgfr

Comment: Hi but doesn't that match three vowels in a row? I'm looking for words like 'beseelen' too, which e.g. has three e's. I just changed the `.*?` to  `\w*?`.

Comment: why do you keep putting `*?`, I'd suggest looking at a regex reference page.  you're saying optionally match zero or more, but allowing zero implies it's optional!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
grep -E --colour=always -i '\b\w*([aeioueöäüèéà])(\w*\1){2,}\w*'
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score -1):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -E '(([aeioueöäüèéà])[^\2]*){3,}' input_file
```